# Unable to connect to a NATed peer

Tags: jxta

I've successfully started **RendezVous_Hans_A_Multicast_Participant** on one PC and on another I've started **Edge_Teyacapan_Another_Multicast_Participant** but the connection between them is not getting established. Both the **PCs are behind the same Wifi router** NAT.

Is this the correct way to connect peers behind a Wifi router using JXTA 2.6 ? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Holly,

Please do use JXTA version 2.7 instead of 2.6. Also, can you post the log messages that JXTA spits out. The messages are very helpful in finding out the problem.

Thanks

DD